# How to parallelise a nested loop in dask

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I have the following code:

```
while (i< 10):
  for i in range(0, len(df_1)):
      new_df_1 = df_1.iloc[i]
      for j in (len(df_2)):
         new_df_2 = df_2.iloc[j]
         client.compute(self.func(i, new_df_1, new_df_2), scheduler="processes"), 
          break
```

I don't know how to use dask in such a nested loops to speed up the code. I tried to make the inner function as a function like below, but raises error.

This is what I have tried:

```
while (i< 10):
  for i in range(0, len(df_1)):
      new_df_1 = df_1.iloc[i]
      def process_l(i, client, new_df_1, new_df_2):
         for j in (len(df_2)):
            new_df_2 = df_2.iloc[j]
            client.compute(self.func(i, new_df_1, new_df_2), scheduler="processes"), 
            break

      client.submit(process_l(i, new_df_1, new_df_2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `.compute()` will stop further execution of the code until the results of `.compute()` are ready. Instead you might want to use `delayed` or `client.submit`. Here's a rough suggestion:

```py
futs = []
# to avoid the while loop
for i in range(0, min(10, len(df_1))):
    new_df_1 = df_1.iloc[i]
    for j in range(0, len(df_2)):
        new_df_2 = df_2.iloc[j]

        # this will submit future and proceed with the code without
        # waiting for the result
        fut = client.submit(self.func, i, new_df_1, new_df_2, scheduler="processes")
        futs.append(fut)

results = client.gather(futs) # this waits for all results
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however this does not change the speed. Nothing changed! I don't know if be possible to make each nested loop in a different processor!?

Comment: Oops, there was a typo in my code. Can you try the updated version?